# Wordpress Website Menu (Header) Not Showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using thrive architect in my website and recently my menu (header) stopped showing up.

I tried many ways to fix it but nothing seems to work. I also created a new menu and set it as the primary menu but that also didn’t solve the problem. I am running an ad on my website.

Comment: Is this a code or settings issue? What do you think? Please give more information

Comment: Debug it. Or atleast provide some sort of code

Answer (score 0):

pls check the Top Bar > General section of the customizer>Header, the menu is enabled or Disabled or provide some more information.